# customize color selection of CIPixellate filter

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter

The user selects an image, which is pixellated more or less based on a slider input:

```
-(CIImage *)pixelPhoto:(CIImage *)img withAmount:(float)inputScale {

// Set up the pixellate filter where the inputScale is provided by the slider.
CIFilter *pixel = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIPixellate"];
[pixel setValue:img forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[pixel setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:inputScale] forKey:@"inputScale"];
CIImage *croppedImage = [pixel.outputImage imageByCroppingToRect:[beginImage extent]];
return croppedImage; }
```

I understand it 'makes an image blocky by mapping the image to colored squares whose color is defined by the replaced pixels'. ([CIFilter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html/%22CIFilter%20Class%20Reference%22)) Imagine a paint-by-number scenario; I'd like to dig a little deeper into CIPixellate and have the color of each square then approximated to a smaller array of about 400 colors.

This is my first venture into manipulating images, or really fooling around with any kind of graphics. I think I'm not having much luck finding the info I need because I don't know enough to have the correct terminology with which to search properly.

It seems like I should be able to pull an array of the squares' colors from the pixellated image data, then iterate through them to apply an algorithm to approximate them to the shorter list of colors I would like to limit them to. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. Do you want to be able to read back the color of each square, or a histogram of colors from within an individual square?

Comment: the color of each square

Comment: In that case, you don't even need to go the pixellation route. You could simply downsample using Core Graphics into a low res image and then read back the RGB pixel values from the result.

Comment: (Still working through some tutorials to understand the clear, precise instructions you gave me. :) )